# Match a date from one table to the next closest date in a calendar table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm using snowflake SQL to add business days to a date using a calendar table. The start date on my left table could be any day, including non-business days. I then need to count up only business days, which I'm doing with LEAD on the calendar table, filtered by whether or not the date is a business day. My current solution works as long as the start date is a business day, so I'm trying to use an IF in the ON clause to:

- Exactly match the date in the right table if it exists
- Round up to the next available date in the right table if no exact match exists

The orders table will have a start_date that could be any day. This example rounds the day up to the next Monday, which works for weekend days, but holidays on weekdays don't work - NEXT_DAY takes it all the way to next Monday, which might bypass several valid workdays and next Monday might be a holiday. I need to always output a due date with no nulls. I want to directly compare the start_date to the calendar table and avoid making assumptions about what is or is not a business day, so all the maintenance happens on the calendar table.

us_work_days_flag on the calendar table defines which days are business days

```
select orders.start_date
,d.date
,d.due_date

from orders

LEFT JOIN (
    Select date
    ,LEAD(date,2)
    OVER (PARTITION BY US_WORK_DAYS_FLAG ORDER BY date) AS Due_Date
    FROM calendar WHERE us_work_days_flag = 1) d
    ON IFF(
            orders.start_date = d.date,
            DATE(orders.start.date) = DATE(d.date),
            NEXT_DAY(tts.last_outbound_dttm,'Monday')=DATE(d.date)
)
```

Example:

Start date: 9-04-2023 (a holiday)

Correct output:

| orders.start_date | d.date | d.due_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9-4-2023 | 9-5-2023 | 9-7-2023 |

I also tried ScottPletcher's method here but Snowflake doesn't support non-scalar correlated queries, so the 'top 3' in the nested select throws an error.

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/add-business-days-to-a-date-using-a-calendar-table#post-1797339

Comment: Top 3 in a subquery doesn't work, but you could use a QUALIFY statement with a window function that only picks 3 records.  I haven't looked in a lot of detail to that solution, but I'd use a CTE and then the QUALIFY to give you the same result as a TOP 3.

Comment: Aren't you just after "the next business day" which might be 1,2,3 or maybe a few more days. The question that gave rise to the use of top 3 is different, there they wanted a specific number of business days to be added (example 3) which is why top 3 was used.  It isn't relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are after a business day that is as close as possible to start_date i.e. >= star_date but you only need 1 such date for each row. I would suggest a lateral join as follows:

```
select
       o.start_date
     , c.next_bus_day
from orders o
LATERAL (
    select date as next_bus_day
    from calendar
    where date >= o.start_date and us_work_days_flag = 1
    ORDER BY date ASC
    LIMIT 1
    ) c
```

Here the subquery looks for a business day that is >= the start_date and due to the order and limit, returns only 1 result.

---

Here is another option that **may** give you a way to find the due date (which is two business days later than the original answer). This is untested!

```
SELECT
      o.start_date
    , c.next_bus_day
    , d.due_date 
FROM orders o 
LATERAL(SELECT date AS next_bus_day 
        FROM calendar WHERE DATE >= o.start_date
        AND us_work_days_flag = 1 
        ORDER BY DATE ASC 
        LIMIT 1
        ) c 
LATERAL(SELECT date AS due_date 
        FROM calendar WHERE DATE >= c.next_bus_day
        AND us_work_days_flag = 1 
        ORDER BY DATE ASC LIMIT 3 OFFSET 2
        ) d
```

Comment: This does work to get the next business day. I'm trying to think how to then do the LEAD and get the due_date, which is two business days later.

Comment: "Match a date from one table to the next closest date in a calendar table" is literally the question. "This does work to get the next business day." seems to be that answer to that specific question.

Comment: I added a possible approach for adding the 2 business days - logic should work - but let's see what happens